# Link custom domain to any GitHub repo

Tags: github, dns, github-pages

I am aware that on GitHub you can create a repository, `<username>.github.io`, which will be a personal website. I also understand you can link custom domains to this, so `example.com` would show the website in your GitHub repo.

I have a couple questions though.

At the moment, I have a GitHub project - let's call it `FooProject`. I have purchased a custom domain name for a website to showcase the project. How can I create a website for this, hosted on GitHub? (not a personal site in the form `<username>.github.io`, but a project site).

Also, can I give the GitHub repository a different name like `fooproject.com`, or does it something specific?

I suppose what I am really asking is, when hosting a website on GitHub...

- Can you host your website using a GitHub repository of any name (like `fooproject.com`)?
- If not, I'm aware of using `gh-pages` branches for the website of a project. How would this work with a custom domain?
- If that isn't a good option either, what's the best option for my use case?

Hope that's clear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So I managed to answer my own questions in the end - here's what I did.

My website is going to be something to showcase a different project I am working on. I could have hosted the website from a `/doc` directory or `gh-pages` branch in my project repository and then set up a custom domain from there.

However, there was also the option of creating a repository with any name and hosting the website from the `master` branch - this method appealed to me more.

I created a new repository named the same as my domain name, `example.com` (it doesn't really matter what you call the repository). Then, using git, I added some website files - `index.html`, `stylesheet.css`, etc.

Once my repository was ready, I configured its `master` branch as a publishing source for GitHub pages - see [this help page for details](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-github-pages/#enabling-github-pages-to-publish-your-site-from-master-or-gh-pages).

Then with my DNS provider (GoDaddy, in my case), I configured the `CNAME` and `A` records (for the `www` subdomain and apex domain respectively). There are also help pages on GitHub for [setting up `www` subdomains](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-a-www-subdomain/) and [setting up apex domains](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-an-apex-domain/). Note that it takes a little while for the changes made on the DNS to take effect.

Finally, I added my custom domain to my GitHub repository - see the GitHub help page for [adding or removing custom domains](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-or-removing-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site/).

---

Here's a summary (for using any GitHub repository to host a website):

1. Create your repository - repository name doesn't matter.
2. Add your website files - HTML, CSS, JavaScript, etc.
3. Configure the `master` branch as a publishing source
4. Configure `CNAME` and `A` records with DNS provider
5. Add the custom domain to the GitHub repository settings